# Facebook Page Feed Fragment Android

Tags: java, android, json, facebook-graph-api

I have searched alot and there is no full "tutorial" on getting public page feed from a facebook page.

I followed http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

but the problem with this is i can't format facebook json data because the 'content' includes status text, images, links and i didn't find a way to seperate and read all that

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&idXXXXXXXXXX

can anybody show a way to fill a fragment with facebook public page statuses